# Visual C++ DrawRectangle filled

Tags: visual-c++, drawrectangle

I'm working with Visual C++ 2008, Express Edition.

I need to design a rectangle filled with the colour. The rectangles I designed
were just unfilled.

```
graphics ^sheet = panel1->CreateGraphics();
System::Drawing::Pen ^biro = 
    gcnew System::Drawing::Pen(System::Drawing::Color::Blue);
foglio->DrawRectangle(biro,System::Drawing::Rectangle::
Rectangle(100,100,10,50));
```

Everything works fine, but I want that THE WHOLE RECTANGLE IS FILLED WITH BLUE.

How do I manage?

Thanks and regards

Uwe_98

Comment: Call `FillRectangle` for the inside, then `DrawRectangle` for a border.

Comment: Do make a minimal effort to check the MSDN documentation for the System.Drawing.Graphics class.  You'll have no trouble finding the Fill methods.  In general, do **not** use CreateGraphics(), whatever you draw won't survive.  Minimize and restore your window for example.  Use the panel's Paint event instead.

Comment: ok, I've found the answer myself. If somebody is interested:  SolidBrush  ^myBrush = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::Red);
g->FillRectangle(myBrush, RectangleF(50, 50, 100, 100)); or
g->FillRectangle(myBrush, Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100)); //It works.

Comment: Thank You very much. I didn't see Your comments at the moment, when I was writing mine. @Hans: Sorry, I did't know these methods, though I'm an' absolute beginner. Thank You 4 Your detailed answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I've tried out Your method, but I had some difficulties to substitute 'CreateGraphics() with panel1->Paint. The rectangles should be designed every time, when I'm in the 'click-event' of 'button one'. So I tried to substitute the panel1->CreateGraphics with the panel1->Paint, but the intellisense told me that I have to put the object and the event into the brackets (System::Object ^sender, ...event ^e). What object and what event does it refer to?