# Draw rectangle on panel Visual C++ using a paint event

Tags: visual-c++, paint

I've painted several rectangles on a panel, using 'CreateGraphics()'. Though they always disappeared after minimizing and restoring the window I used the paint-event in order to restore them and everything works fine, always using 'CreateGraphics().

Sometimes ago Mr. Hans Passant gave me the advice to SUBSTITUTE 'CreateGraphics()' with the paint event of the panel. It seems to me, that the 'paint' event is also used for creating, and not only 4 restoring.

[Visual C++ DrawRectangle filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446405/visual-c-drawrectangle-filled):

> ... In general, do not use CreateGraphics(), whatever you draw won't survive. Minimize and restore your window for example. Use the panel's Paint event instead. – Hans Passant Jul 3 at 12:47

I tried so, but I didn't succeed. I always needed 'CreateGraphics' in order to initialize a pointer to the class 'Graphics' and to use the method 'drawRectangle':

```
System::Drawing::Graphics ^drawPointer = CreateGraphics();
```

After that You create the rectangle with

```
drawPointer->drawRectangle(...);
```

But going into the 'paint-event' of the panel, how do I reach the method 'drawRectangle' without using 'CreateGraphics()'? Or did I get the advice in the wrong way?

Comment: Use e->Graphics->DrawRectangle() in the Paint event handler.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I get you right, but usually you get a painting capability like this:

```
System::Void Paint(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) {
System::Drawing::Graphics^ g = e->Graphics;
    g->DrawRectangle(...);
}
```